# How to connect to a remote server using PuTTY generated key

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, putty, remote-server, ssh-keys

I'm trying to connect to a remote server using **Remote Explorer** extension in VSCode but when I use putty generate private key `private.ppk` I get an error

> Could not establish a connection to

When I read through the error log, at the point it tried to load key `C:\Users\user\.ssh\private.ppk`, it says

> Invalid Format

How can I use PuTTY format key to connect? Below is how my `config` looks like

```
Host ###.##.##.###
  HostName ###.##.##.###
  User <user>
  Port 22
  IdentityFile C:\Users\user\.ssh\private.ppk
```

Answer (score 12):

The .ppk is a proprietary key format of PuTTY. Most other tools do not support it.

You will probably have to convert the key to OpenSSH format. Use PuTTYgen for that. Load the key and go to *Conversions > Export OpenSSH key*.